# What is the difference between debugDescription and description methods of an array in swift?

Tags: swift

Swift documentation says

```
debugDescription = A textual representation of self, suitable for debugging
description = A textual representation of self
```

in playground i get the output of both call as same

```
anArray.debugDescription // "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"
anArray.description // "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"
```

What is the actual difference between the two ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From Apple documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html)

> an object's debug description is the same as its description. However,
>   you can override debugDescription if you want to decouple these; many
>   Cocoa objects do this.

So basically unless you add any extra functionality to your debugDescription it will be the same as description.

Comment: when is each called?

Comment: we can override `description` as well by confirming to CustomStringConvertible protocol